# What is the difference between a macaron and an amaretti biscuit?

Tags: cookies, macarons

Other than differing in origin (Italian (amaretti) and France (Macaron)), what is the difference between these two biscuits?

Comment: Macaron are Italian, Macaroon are French and these are quite different. I'm assuming your are referring to the Italian Macaron as these are the closer of the two to Amaretti?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this article](http://www.thenibble.com/reviews/main/cookies/cookies2/history-of-macaroons.asp) the main difference is that French macaroons are usually sandwiched together and enjoyed alone while amaretti (pre-cursor to French macaroons) are used both as a cookie and often as an ingredient.  Both are prepared from almond paste and meringue.

Answer (score 2):

Macron are in my experience much softer and more meringue like than amaretti, which are much more firm with a biscuit like texture.